# Java evaluating mathematical expressions from strings

Tags: java, math

I have strange task to do in Java.
Without using any loops and if statements i have to develop simple calculator which defines all operations and numbers in one String like: "126.7214        +  121"
I used regex to parse string and get 3 string variables ['125.7214', '+' ,'121'], normally i would do if statement, parseString to integer and do if statement based on math symbol to sum those numbers, but I cant. Is there any trick in Java to do it faster? Some ready-to go library?
I would appreciate any advice. :code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Calc {

    public String doCalc(String cmd) {

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(cmd);
        m.find();
        String num1= m.group(0);
        m.find();
        String znak = m.group(0);
        m.find();
        String num2 = m.group(0);





        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a strict guarantee on the form, like saying it has to be always 'x <op> y'?

Comment: Are you able to use switch() and cases?

Comment: A library method is probably going to loop while parsing - is that an issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: regular expression are very poor to such evaluation. Give some parts (atoms) but not structure / relations /sense in excpression

Comment: no problem if any imported method uses a loop, but it has to be standard library. switch is not allowed too...

Comment: There is no expression evaluator library in Java SE.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript parser works well for expressions.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
public class Expression{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ScriptEngineManager script = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine eng = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    System.out.println(eng.eval("5+5*5"));
    } 
}
```

Comment: @jawjaw No problem. If this is a personal project, the next challenge can be defining, storing, and parsing variables such as x = 5, y = 5/2 so that you can evaluate things like x + y.

Comment: Thanks, no its Java exercise with BigDecimal Calculator in tricky way:) but thanks nice to know that executing some code this way can be that easy

Answer (score 2):

If you're not allowed to use switch and case either there are libraries that can help you:

- [EvalEx](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx) - Personally I like this one.
- [JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/)
- Commons Math: The Apache Commons Mathematics Library

Other wise you could implement a Polish Calculator

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring's SPeL to evaluate your values.  SPeL stands for Spring Expression Language. It allows you to evaluate a String that is written in Java.  The following line is an example of what you can evaluate within an expression.  I imagine you could simply put your values within the expression to get the values out.  Of course this isn't a fully working with all the dependencies.  This example is simply showing you a simply example showing you it easily possible.

```
//From www.mkyong.com
Expression exp2 = parser.parseExpression("'Hello World'.length()");
```

Of course you can refer to the Spring site in order to learn more about how to create a Spring project with the dependencies along with several examples that are fully flushed out.  I received this small snippet from the mkyong site.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/test-spring-el-with-expressionparser/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that leverages polymorphy (since you already know how to parse the operands, I've left that part out because of sheer laziness on my part):

```
import java.util.*;

public class CalcProofOfConcept {

    public static abstract class Arithmetic { public abstract double apply(double x, double y); }

    public static class Add extends Arithmetic { public double apply(double x, double y) { return x+y; } }
    public static class Subtract extends Arithmetic { public double apply(double x, double y) { return x-y; } }
    public static class Multiply extends Arithmetic { public double apply(double x, double y) { return x*y; } }
    public static class Divide extends Arithmetic { public double apply(double x, double y) { return x/y; } }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Map<String, Arithmetic> operators = new HashMap<String, Arithmetic>();
        operators.put("+", new Add());
        operators.put("-", new Subtract());
        operators.put("*", new Multiply());
        operators.put("/", new Divide());

        double x = 125.7214;
        double y = 121;
        String op = "+";

        System.out.println(operators.get(op).apply(x,y));
    }
}
```

This prints `246.72140000000002`.

By the way: actual arithmetic expressions are a [context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), so for anything more than the simplest forms, using a regular expression to parse them won't work. Once you mix addition and multiplication, for instance, a regex-based calculator would give wrong results because it can't respect operator precedence.

PS: *Yes, I know this is breaking a nut with a sledgehammer but I just thought it'd be a cool way to do it...*